# Do DevExpress WPF control libaries work with AvaloniaUI in .NetCore?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, devexpress-wpf, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm working on coming up to speed with the latest release of AvaloniaUI (Avalonia 0.9.0 Release).
We have an WPF application we are building using the .Net Core framework.
We have been making extensive use of the DevExpress WPF control libraries.

Do the DevExpress WPFlibraries work with the AvaloniaUI framework?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: AvaloniaUI is similar to but not exactly WPF, so unless DevExpress gives you a confirmation the answer should be clear no. That can also explain why Xamarin Forms/Uno Platform are better options with third party support.

Comment: Note that commercial 3rd party WPF/UWP controls quite often use platform-specific APIs. For example we've tried to port open-source controls from Telerik and discovered that they have a custom DirectX rendering engine that obviously doesn't work on Linux and OSX.

Comment: I've had some communication with the folks over @ DevExpress. They say internally that they use native WPF controls. Does this mean the two should play well together? JB